# The provided anti-forgery token was meant for a different claims-based user - OAUTH2

Tags: .net, authentication, oauth, asp.net-mvc-5

I have just implemented a system to test that uses MVC5 and authentication handled by Google+ OAUTH2. Everything seems to work fine, but I have noticed an issue straight after the initial registration.

So the process seems to be that users login to their Google account which then routes to a registration page that ties that Google user to a user profile in my system.

If a user goes through this process and then starts using the system (which is mostly Ajax loaded) and presses the browsers 'back' button they then get thrown back to the registration page. From then on in that session they get plagued with this error 'The provided anti-forgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user'

Now, I can tell people not use use the back button, but we all know how successful that message will be..

Is there anything I can do to detect a back button click, or something to prevent a user ever getting back to the registration page again? I think the registration page must be directed to from the Google code as I don't recall building it!!

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You'll want to prevent your pages from caching so that on back it always tries to reload the page from the server, thus generating a new anti-forgery token that is valid for your now logged in user.